# How to refer a jar outside exe in Java desktop application?

Tags: java, jar, desktop, patch, launch4j

I have a Java application installed. The jar is bundled into an .exe file using Launch4J. Now I want to create a patch for this application.

If I create another jar containing only updated files, how can I refer it in the original code?

Comment: I use Launch 4J to create exe

Answer (score 1):

> I have java application installed. ..Now I want to create a patch for this application.

This is one of the strengths of the [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) launch technology that comes with the J2SE.  Simply update the Jar on the server, and the next time the app. launches, it will be updated.

The update can be honed for your use-case, configured to be done lazily or eagerly, before or after launch, or even programatically controlled using the JNLP API's [DownloadService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html).

> ..And the jar is bundlled into an .exe file ..

'Unfortunately', JWS works on Windows, ..and Mac., and *nix - so you may have to expand your horizons.

---

BTW - I have no idea how to do the same with Launch4J, but then, that is really the wrong question.  I aim to provide an answer to the *right* question, which is *"How do I deploy & update a Java rich client?"*. ;)

Comment: A down-voter does not like JWS apparently.  Care to share why?

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with Launch4J, however I think you should try to affect the classpath. JRE always loads the classes from the classpath. From this point of view, jars have no added value and just serve as a containers for your *.class files and resources.
Now, if you succeed to configure your tool to do something like:
classpath = C:\Temp\my_patch_path;$your_current_classpath
then its enough to put your changed files into C:\Temp\my_patch_path (of course preserving the package structure). JRE will load your classes first in this case.
Hope, this helps

Mark

Answer (score 0):

It is might not be possible to do this without changing the contents of the exe.